# Skip lines when reading from csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large csv file containing weather observations from the Bureau of Meteorology. When reading from this file, I need to skip over some lines at the start.

The file looks like this:

```
"Daily Weather Observations..."
"Prepared..."

,"Date","Minimum temperature (�C)", ...
# data here
```

When reading from the file, I want to skip over the lines at the start which are not the data. However, the number of these lines vary from file to file. (I have many files.)

My current approach is:

```
import pandas as pd
actuals = pd.read_csv(path_here, skiprows=5, encoding='latin1')
```

However, this only works when I hardcode in the rows, and I need it to be able to dynamically skip over the rows.

How can I skip over these 'commentary' lines when reading from the csv file?

Comment: First open the file with python, identify your header and compute the number of lines to skip to pass to `read_csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in an open file object to the `read_csv` function.  So you can open the file, read the lines until you find what you need, then pass the remainder to the data frame.  You will need to pass in the column names manually, or parse the those from last `line` as well.

```
import pandas as pd

with open('weather.csv') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith(',"Date"'):
            break
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, header=None, names=['Date', 'MinTemp', ...])
```

Comment: You might use `line` to automatically get the names ;)

Comment: @mozway, yes. I would probably pass the line through a `csv.reader` to make sure it parses correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the first character in the line is data when you read it, you can have your read_csv function read the data from the beginning of the line with #.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).